# How to add buttons below action bar

Tags: java, android, xml, button, actionbarsherlock

can anyone show me how can i add buttons below action bar?
I mean that three buttons (Post, Checkin, Refresh) who are stretched perfectly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYhuE.png

Sorry for my very bad english

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You would include that in your layout for the `Activity`. That's not part of the `ActionBar` area.

Comment: Thanks, can you say how can i reach something like that?

Comment: How to add buttons to a layout? That's a pretty basic question. You should look for some Android tutorials to familiarize yourself with the platform.

Comment: no you don't understand me i can add buttons to a layout, but how can i reach that all buttons have the same width to fill screen ?

Comment: @user1783510 Give this attribute to each of your buttons: `android:layout_weight="1"`